# Cast raw pointer of array to unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++14, unique-ptr

I am working against a blackbox framework (cdg), which fills an array of `uint32_t` with values. 
The call looks like that:

```
std::size_t dataCount = 100;
uint32_t* data = new uint32_t[dataCount];
cdg.generate(data);
```

Unfortunately, the framework doesn't use templates, so I have to pass in a `uint32_t*`. To get rid of the raw pointer I want to "wrap" it into a `std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>`. Thus it is an array I think I have to use a 
`std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[]>`. Is there a way to convert the raw pointer into a `unique_ptr` or should I do something like that:

```
const std::size_t dataCount = 100;
std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[]> data = std::make_unique<uint_32_t[]>(dataCount);
cdg.generate(data.get());
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`, and `std::vector::data()`?

Comment: Why not use a vector of uint32_t?

Comment: And if `dataCount` is constant, use `std::array`

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: @gurka the array-option is valid, but I'd argue against it whenever there is a doubt about the constness in the requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smart pointers are great and all, but perhaps consider using `std::vector`, since you note that it is an array.

You can get a pointer to the data as it were a C array (for your legacy interface) with [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

```
std::vector<uint32_t> nums(100);   // creates a vector of size 100
uint32_t *ptr = nums.data();
cdg.generate(ptr);                 // passes uint32_t* as needed
```

If you need to ensure unique ownership, `unique_ptr` is the right choice. But it sounded like you really just wanted something that will clean up your array, but still gives a raw pointer for C methods.

Comment: The array should be processed by an amount of "workers". To do this, I want to "split" the array and pass it to the workers like that:

    std::size_t workerCount = 10;
    std::size_t workCount = dataCount / workerCount;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < workerCount; ++i) {
       ProcessClass a((data + offset), workCount);
       a.doSomething();
       offset += workCount;
    }


To avoid confusion about the ownership of my pointer I want to use a smartpointer. Is this even possible using a vector?

Comment: Yes, as noted in the [data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) docs, the expression `data() + offset` is valid, as long as offset is less than `size()`

Comment: There is no problem with concurrent work in a `std::vector`'s data as long as you do not (re)move or append entries to it.

Comment: This is awesome! And if the std::vector or std::array is a private member of my class, the stl container takes care of (de)allocation at all, right?

Comment: Yep, vector's destructor will be called in classic RAII fashion when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: Maybe one could add that `&nums[0]` can be used instead of [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) for C++ versions before C++11.

Comment: I tried to use a std::array but it seems to cause a segmentation fault. The array holds 84.000.000 uint32_t. Does that mean, that I just can't use a std::array and that I have to use a std::vector or is this a reason to use a unique_ptr?

Comment: Read up on stack vs heap in C++. It sounds to me that number is too great to fit in stack memory, so std::array just might not work. But the way with std::vector should still be good

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer